# Set different multiple values to different multiple text boxes using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am creating a script in which admin can add charge for all domestic regions and can also add charge for international regions. The scenario is :-

Admin clicks the add charge button. There he can add charge,cost and delivery days. Now i want to set value of `charge` to all text boxes   having `name = delivery_charge[<?php echo $AddIndex; ?>][charge]`, set value of `cost` to all text boxes having `name=delivery_charge[<?php echo $AddIndex; ?>][cost]` and set value of `delivery_days` to all text boxes having `name=delivery_charge[<?php echo $AddIndex; ?>][days]`.

What i've done is

```
function addCharges(type){
var cost = parseFloat($('#modal-cost').val());
var charge = parseFloat($('#modal-charge-box').val());
var days = parseInt($('#modal-days').val());

if(isNaN(cost)){
    cost = 0;
}

if(isNaN(charge)){
    charge = 0;
}

if(isNaN(days)){
    days = 0;
}

if(type == 'domestic'){
    $('.domesticZones :checkbox').prop("checked", true);
    $('.domesticZones input').prop("readonly", false);

   //What code should i put here so that all text box with name delivery_charge[][cost] have value of cost and same for variables charge and days.


}else if(type == 'international'){
    $('.internationalZones :checkbox').prop("checked", true);
}
}
```

Comment: could you post relevant HTML code generated from the php script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
// find name with [cost] at the end of name
$('input[name$="[cost]"]').val(cost);
// same goes to the others
```

The updated comment should do the trick, and you can try this solution also by using regex, but this need quite extra new line compared with above code :

```
$('input[name$="[cost]"]').filter(function(){
  // find the attribute name start with `delivery_charge` 
  // name and not followed by `_`
  var regex = /delivery_charge(?!\_)/;
  if ( regex.test( $(this).attr('name') ) ) return this;              
}).val(cost);
```

Read this [**Doc**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) and look at this [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/nbd1nfs4/).

Comment: It works but it also changes the value of text-boxes having `name=delivery_charge_international[<?php echo $AddIndex; ?>][days]`

Comment: * `[cost]` not `days`

Comment: Solved. used  this  `$('.domesticZones input[name$="[cost]').val(cost);`.

Comment: Glad to hear that mate